# Oracle sqlldr convert date field with different NLS_DATE_FORMAT

Tags: oracle

I want to load data file which contains date fields in this format:

```
10-AUG-16
```

but, my oracle NLS_LANG is "Simplified Chinese_China.ZH16GBK", if I specify date format in control file like this:

```
dd-Month-YY
```

It will fail, as it expect data like this:

```
10-八月 -16 // 八月 means august in Chinese
```

how can I load this data?

Comment: What Oracle version?

Comment: @Phil oracle version is 11g

Comment: I'm not sure how the language will factor in, but from a pure English standpoint, your data format mask does not match your data.  If your data is '10-Aug-16', then your mask would be 'dd-Mon-yy', not 'dd-Month-yy'.  That's assuming the '10' really is the day.  And it's long past time to lose the 2-digit years.  Legions of guys like me busted our butts to fix that 16 years ago.  Don't repeat the mistakes that lead to Y2K.

Answer (score 2):

`TO_DATE` functions accepts the NLS language as an optional parameter .. have you tried pulling it in via SQL*Loader as a `CHAR`, then do a `TO_DATE` conversion on it inline?

so your SQL*loader syntax might look like:

```
  ...
    my_date     CHAR  "TO_DATE(:my_date, 'dd-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American')"
  ...
```

See if that works any better ??